# List contents of highlighted cells in separate sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I'm working in Excel and I'm trying to compile a list of issues on the first sheet "Summary." I have another sheet, "PhoneToolData" where any duplicate entries are highlighted. How can I get the contents of each of the highlighted cells into the list on my Summary sheet?

Comment: Kendra, what kind of model do you need? Automatic? By hand? isn't conditional formatting for duplicate values and copying it to first page appropriate?

Comment: Automatic. This doc regularly imports updated information so I need that to be automatically reflected in the summary page.

Comment: i think you could use conditional formatting(CF) for duplicate values. If there are more than one column you need to use formula in your CF. you could have more info about formulas in CF: https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-duplicate-rows  and the rest is filter>copy>paste

Comment: But copying and pasting is manual and will need to be manually updated every time the data is updated. I'm trying to automate the process.

Comment: use macro recording for copy-paste operation. put the generated code in teh Summary sheet's change event

Answer (score 0):

See [Link Cells Between Tabs and Workbooks in Excel](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/link-cells-between-tabs-and-workbooks-and-in-excel-2010/) for more information. This is a very helpful article for what you are wanting to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps.